# Alternatives to twitter for large daily or weekly samples for sentiment analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, twitter, api

Twitter, with their API, including the free tier, has been a go-to source for collecting large samples of texts expressing sentiment on various topics of interest. I just started a project in December to collect, over the long term, sentiment about automated vehicles (https://www.mcgurrin.info/sentiment/AVsentiment.shtml) and electric vehicles (https://www.mcgurrin.info/sentiment/EVsentiment.shtml).

Now, however, Twitter has announced that they will end free access, and Elon Musk has tweeted that the new "basic" tier may cost $100 per month for access!

What, if any, good alternatives to Twitter are there for a good, free or very low cost set of posts, with significant daily or at least weekly volumes?

Comment: I'm in a similar bind, as I was just about to start pulling some data for my thesis. I'm looking at Facebook and Reddit as alternatives. I don't yet know what data I will be able to get from it, if any.

Comment: In going through the literature on what I'm currently working on (sentiment regarding electric vehicles and regarding automated vehicles), I've come across papers where Reddit was used and also a couple that pulled YouTube comments. Don't know if that helps for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since X, is charging 100$ per month, another alternative would be to use selenium..to scrap the data automated way.

Comment: I've tried that, but it only "sort of" works. Whereas with the old API, I was pulling in hundreds of new tweets each time, I can't seem to pull even 100 with that approach (which includes scrolling to, in theory, see all items returned.